# jquery click/mouseenter/mouseleave change class

Tags: jquery, click, mouseenter, mouseleave

I am tring do some effect. the defualt select word is the first li.

```
ul {
    list-style: none
}
.a-c {
    color: #c10603;
    cursor: pointer
}
```

```
<ul>
    <li class="a a-c">list1</li>
    <li class="a">list2</li>
    <li class="a">list3</li>
    <li class="a">list4</li>
    <li class="a">list5</li>
</ul>
```

when I click another li, the default will change. some code working well.

```
$('body').on('click','.a', function(){
    $('.a-c').removeClass('.a-c');
    $(this).addClass('.a-c')
});
```

Now I need another effect, when mouse hover li, the defaut li will change color into black,  and the one which mouseenter will change color into the `color:#c10603`, some code also working.

```
$('body').on('mouseenter','.a', function(){
    $(this).addClass('a-c')
});
$('body').on('mouseleave','.a', function(){
    $('.a').removeClass('a-c')
});
```

But I also need, if mouseleave all the li, the defult li will still show color as `#c10603`

Some online code here http://jsfiddle.net/3rvd8qwf/1/  my problem is when i click another li and mouseleave all the li, the defualt li should change into the one which I clicked, not always the first one. Thanks.

Comment: why you are using hover css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be handled by CSS alone; and one less jQuery function:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="active">List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li{
    font-size: 28px;
}

li.active{
    color: red;
}

ul:hover li{
    color: black;
}

li:hover{
    color: red !important;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").click(function(){
        $("li.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Check out the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mk779g3o/

Answer (score 1):

You can have a CSS only solution, so no mouseenter etc required:

```
ul:hover,
ul:hover .a-c {
    color: black;
}
```

And the click function (please note you don't need the class dot when using `addClass()` or `removeClass()`:

```
$('.a').on('click', function() {

    $('.a').removeClass('a-c');
    $(this).addClass('a-c');

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmp6x8u9/